# why node js donot provide a [Mother]function to call any function asynchronously with a supplied call back

Tags: node.js, generics, asynchronous, callback, platform

*Given Node.js boasts of asynchronous event driven model*, 
I was expecting, I should be able to write any Nodejs function, 
e.g as  simple as going through a loop, e.g **IamLooper()** below,
which might or might not involve file I/O  and then pass that looping function to a mother nodeJs  function e.g **Invoke()**,to which  I also pass  another  call back functiont e.g **happyend()** below.

My expectation  was after IamLooper is finished ,happyend () will be invoked by the NodeJs supplied function .

e.g :
==>

```
 gdata =[];
function IamLooper() {
var pi = Array;

for (var ii = 0 ; ii <4 ; ii ++)
{  
  pi[ii] = 13* ii;;
 gdata.push(ii);

}
console.log("looper  done -tell the callback") ;
}
function  happyend() { console.log("looper says done");}
```

I want to invoke IamLooper() and supply the happyend at   time of invocation.
i.e. I am looking for a ready made node function e.g Invoke,  which can be called like this:

```
  Invoke(IamLooper(), happyend());
  if(gdata.length > 0) {console.log("looping has started");}
```

In essence Invoke should do the same for any two functions I supply to it so that we have just a **working template of a callback execution strategy**.
Also the Invoke being executed async, my program progresses beyond Invoke before it finishes.
Is my expectation is misguided ?  Can any one give me some guidance here.

Comment: It can be argued Async.js provides something  similar , however my main question  remains is  how do you write a nodejs  function from scratch  only using node js [i.e. with no C library calls] ,  that can be invoked and a call back function supplied when it is invoked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a preexisting way of easily doing callbacks in node, you should use event emitters (https://nodejs.org/api/events.html):

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var eventExample = new EventEmitter;

//You can create event listeners:
eventExample.on('anEvent', function(someData){
    //Do something with someData
});

//To trigger an event listener you must emit:
eventExample.emit('anEvent', someData);
```

With your code, it'd look something like this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var looper = new EventEmitter;

looper.on('invoke', function(data){
    var callFunction = data.callFunction;
    var finishFunction = data.finishFunction;
    var callParameters = data.callParameters;
    var finishParameters = data.finishParameters;
    if(callParameters == null){
        callFunction({callbackPara: finishParameters, callbackFunction: finishFunction});
    }
    else{
        callFunction(callParameters, {callbackParameters: finishParameters, callbackFunction: finishFunction});
    }
});

looper.on('finish', function(data){
    var finishFunction = data.callbackFunction;
    var parameters = data.callbackParameters;
    if(parameters == null){
        finishFunction();
    }
    else{
        finishFunction(parameters);
    }
});


gdata =[];
function IamLooper(g, callback){
    var pi = Array;
    for (var ii = 0 ; ii <4 ; ii ++){  
        pi[ii] = 13* ii;;
        g.push(ii);
    }
    looper.emit('finish', callback);
}

function  happyend() { console.log("looper says done");}
```

And then call it like:

```
looper.emit('invoke', {callFunction: IamLooper, finishFunction: happyend, callParameters: gdata, finishParameters: null});
```

You can also always do normal callbacks:

```
gdata =[];
function IamLooper(g, callback){
    var pi = Array;
    for (var ii = 0 ; ii <4 ; ii ++){  
        pi[ii] = 13* ii;;
        g.push(ii);
    }
    callback();
}
IamLooper(gdata, function(){ console.log("looper says done");}
```

Comment: Node has its own event loop so that it can watch for events without interfering with other code (https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-nodejs-event-loop).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; there was a small error /typo? - the invoke event should have only the function name without parenthesis in the finishfunction like this: looper.emit('invoke', {callFunction: IamLooper, finishFunction: happyend , callParameters: gdata, finishParameters: null}); . But more importantly this is a good pattern with its own DSL  for Callbacks in node js ! Cheers

Comment: I should add Async Callbacks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I must have done the parentheses out of habit. I'll fix it now. Good luck with your program.